# Group by week query getting error

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL group by week query is like below but in that am getting following error.

> Column 'timesheet.timesheet_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Can anybody help me in this regard

My query :

```
select 
   DatePart(week, timesheet_date),
   count(timesheet.timesheet_id) as TimeSheetID,
   timesheet.timesheet_date,
   timesheet.start_time,
   timesheet.end_time, 
   timesheet.timesheet_status_id,
   timesheet.is_deleted,
   timesheet.created_by,
   timesheet.modified_by,
   timesheet.created_date,
   task.name,
   project.name,
   [user].first_name, [user].last_name 
from 
   timesheet, task, project, [user] 
where 
   task_id = (select task_id from project_task 
              where project_task_id = timesheet.project_task_id) 
   and project_id = (select project_id from project_task 
                     where project_task_id = timesheet.project_task_id) 
   and [user].user_id = timesheet.user_id 
   and timesheet.user_id = 30 
group by 
   timesheet.timesheet_id
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Have you tried finding out what the error message is trying to tell you? It's quite an unambiguous message.

Comment: @astander That's SQL Server.

Comment: Here am using MS-Sql server

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: @Tomalkak ya i tried .if i put count function for every column then the query get execute.but i want query group by week

Comment: @marc_s i am using bulder but it is a sample query

Comment: @marc_s i am using bulder but it is a sample query

Comment: @King: Please vote up answers that helped you. It's a sign of gratitude and courtesy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception message, I will assume SQL Server.

for aggregations (SUM/MAX/MIN/COUNT) you need tol include all columns in the GROUP BY that is not part of an aggregate.

So for your query, you would have something like

```
select  DatePart(week, timesheet_date),
        count(timesheet.timesheet_id) as TimeSheetID,
        timesheet.timesheet_date,
        timesheet.start_time,
        timesheet.end_time,
        timesheet.timesheet_status_id,
        timesheet.is_deleted,
        timesheet.created_by,
        timesheet.modified_by,
        timesheet.created_date,
        task.name,
        project.name,
        [user].first_name,
        [user].last_name 
from    timesheet,
        task,
        project,
        [user] 
where   task_id = (select task_id from project_task where project_task_id=timesheet.project_task_id) 
and project_id = (select project_id from project_task where project_task_id=timesheet.project_task_id) 
and [user].user_id = timesheet.user_id 
and timesheet.user_id =30 
group by    DatePart(week, timesheet_date),
            timesheet.timesheet_date,
            timesheet.start_time,
            timesheet.end_time,
            timesheet.timesheet_status_id,
            timesheet.is_deleted,
            timesheet.created_by,
            timesheet.modified_by,
            timesheet.created_date,
            task.name,
            project.name,
            [user].first_name,
            [user].last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select  DatePart(week, timesheet_date),
        count(timesheet.timesheet_id) as TimeSheetID,
        timesheet.timesheet_date,
        timesheet.start_time,
        timesheet.end_time,
        timesheet.timesheet_status_id,
        timesheet.is_deleted,
        timesheet.created_by,
        timesheet.modified_by,
        timesheet.created_date,
        task.name,
        project.name,
        [user].first_name,
        [user].last_name 
from    timesheet,
        task,
        project,
        [user] 
where   task_id = (select task_id from project_task where project_task_id = timesheet.project_task_id) 
and project_id = (select project_id from project_task where project_task_id = timesheet.project_task_id) 
and [user].user_id = timesheet.user_id 
and timesheet.user_id =30 
group by timesheet.timesheet_id,
        timesheet.timesheet_date;
```